# How to test Stripe `SignatureVerificationError` in Python

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, stripe-payments

For python, the standard stripe webhook code example includes:

```py
    event = None
    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret)
    except ValueError as e:
        logger.error(f"*** Stripe invalid payload: {e = }")
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        logger.error(f"*** Stripe invalid signature: {e = }")
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

I've tried to test this with the following test that inherits from Django testcase:

```py
class TestStripeWebhookView(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("logging.Logger.error")
    @mock.patch("lettergun.apps.payments.views.create_order")
    @mock.patch("lettergun.apps.payments.views.stripe")
    def test_signature_verification_error(self, stripe, create_order, error):
        stripe.Webhook.construct_event.side_effect = SignatureVerificationError

        data = {
            "type": "placeholder",
        }

        response = self.client.get(
            reverse("payments:stripe_webhook"),
            data,
            HTTP_ACCEPT="application/json",
            HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE='placeholder_signature"}',
        )

        error.assert_called_with(f"*** Stripe invalid signature: e = an error message")
        assert not create_order.called
        assert response.status_code == 400
```

This produces the following error which I dont understand:

```
> except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
E TypeError: catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

How can I test that the signature verification error will have the expected effects?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [test cases](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python/blob/master/tests/test_webhook.py#L79) in the `stripe-python` library as a reference. There are quite a number of test cases for signature verification errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by changing the view code from:

```py
except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        logger.error(f"*** Stripe invalid signature: {e = }")
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

to

```py
except SignatureVerificationError as e:
        logger.error(f"*** Stripe invalid signature: {e = }")
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
```

and adding an additional import to the module:

```py
import stripe
from stripe.error import SignatureVerificationError  # Add this line
```

I don't understand why this makes a difference, if anyone can explain I'd be grateful! I expect it's because I'm mocking the stripe object in the test which is clobbering too many things. Importing the error separately prevents it from being overridden by `unittest.mock.patch`, perhaps.

With these changes, the test runs as expected.